# Making processes act differently depend on whether if it has received a message from another process?

Tags: c, mpi

My program needs Process 0 to keep incrementing a counter and send messages until it receives a message from the last process in the program, which then have Process 0 decrement the same counter and send messages. I don't know how to "Listen"/Poll whether a message has been received

My Case: (i is counter)

> While Process 0 Has not received 0 from process 1, i++ and send message.
>
> After Process 0 received the message, i-- and send message.

Or in a more general sense:

> While Process 0 has not received message from process 1, do A
>
> After Process 0 has received the message from process 1, do B

How do I do this in MPI?

Thanks Alot!

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried doing anything with MPI yet?

Comment: Its a book problem, I am learning mpi on my own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you would use `MPI_Isend`, `MPI_Irecv`, and `MPI_Test` for polling. Read your book's chapters on nonblocking communication.

Comment: Thank you so much, it appears that the book only had the non-blocking commands explained quite a while later.